# Hi I am trying to find duplicates on google sheets, however, the formula =COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A)>1

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

Hi I am trying to find duplicates on google sheets, however, the formula =COUNTIF(A1:A,A1:A)>1 keeps highlighting headings, How will i combine it with =REGEXMATCH(A1:A,".com") to find duplicate links only instead of highlighting headings/other data in the same column

Answer (score 0):

logical multiplicaion:

```
=(COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1)*(REGEXMATCH(A1, ".com"))
```